# How to detect keyboard language in SwiftUI's Textfield

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, textfield

I was wondering is there any native keyboard current input using `UITextInputMode.activeInputModes` to check the current keyboard language. I am doing it using this way. But it detects the language just once, when you swift keyboard the value is always `true`

```
class KeyboardHandler: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var isAr = false
    
    init() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange(_:)), name: UITextInputMode.currentInputModeDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    }
    
    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }
    
    @objc private func keyboardWillChange(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let inputMode = UITextInputMode.activeInputModes.first(where: { $0.primaryLanguage == "ar" }) {
            let lang = inputMode.primaryLanguage
            isAr = lang == "ar"
            print(isAr)
        }
    }
}
```

In my SwiftUI i am receiving the notification using this:

```
.onReceive(keyboardHandler.$isAr) { isAr in
            print(isAr)
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You should report a bug to Apple. The `Notification` received for the `UITextInputMode.currentInputModeDidChangeNotification` notification is supposed to have the newly selected `UITextInputMode` set on the notification's `object` property. But in SwiftUI code, the notification's `object` property is `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the notification object as UITextInputMode and check it for the activate language.

```
@objc private func keyboardWillChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    guard let inputMode = notification.object as? UITextInputMode,
          let lang = inputMode.primaryLanguage else { return }

    isAr = lang == "ar"
    print(isAr)
}
```

Comment: it doesn't detect anything!

Comment: This code *should* work but when used in a SwiftUI app, the `object` property of the notification is `nil`.